# Problemas con cakephp 2.8.8 => Notice (1024): Element Not Found: Elements\default.ctp [CORE\Cake\View\View.php, line 425]

Tags: php, bootstrap, cakephp

Tengo problemas al mostrar un mensaje de notificacion cuando guardo, edito o elimino uso boostrap para darle estilo a la pagina web, las lineas de codigo es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

el de arriba es el controlador de editar y el mensaje que me aparece es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Comment: Ayudaría mejor si copias y pegas el código, al igual que el mensaje de error en lugar de una imagen: así podríamos copiar y evaluar. Por cierto, bienvenido al sitio, date una vuelta por: http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask para que te familiarices. Saludos :D

Comment: Muchas gracias por la bienvenida :D me creeras que luego de postear encontré la solucion ajajaja editare el tema por si alguien mas tiene el mismo error Saludos y me dare una vuelta por tu enlace!!

Comment: de nada hermano, agrega la solución a tu pregunta y colabora para que todo el sitio siga creciendo :D Luego de 2 días podrás aceptar la respuesta (el check estará habilitado)

Comment: brother, me refería a que agregues la solución en la parte de abajo donde dice "Tu Respuesta"

Comment: Oh sorry es que soy nuevo en la pagina lo corregire

Comment: normal hermano, entre todos aprendemos, este sitio es de colaboración conjunta, es una hermandad :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema era el siguiente:

El mensaje que cake me estaba dando es que no encontraba el archivo en esta ruta:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\lib\Cake\View\Elements\Default.ctp`

Era porque el archivo estaba en:

`C:\xampp\htdocs\proyecto\lib\Cake\View\Elements\Flash\Default.ctp`